# Is there any way to Querying On deleted Document on SOLR?

Tags: solr

I want to know is there any way to find out which docs has been deleted on SOLR?

Is there any way to execute query on them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there should be at least some low level api that allows you to get the docIds of deleted docs at Lucene level.

But, I wonder if you should not provide your own 'soft delete' feature, with [atomic updates](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Updating+Parts+of+Documents) for instance, so you can delete/undelete docs at your leisure.

Comment: there actual problem is when im uploading 10,000 docs per minute solr somehow decides to make some of them as deleted docs. i want to find out which docs are them and why SOLR acts like that.

Comment: No no way they are coming from sql server with PK as it id